# How to return new table when join multi table in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net

```
public List<Book> getListBooks(int top)
    {
        var result = (from book in db.Books
                      join author in db.Authors on book.AuthorID equals author.ID
                      join publisher in db.Publishers on book.PublisherID equals publisher.ID
                      join category in db.BookCategories on book.CategoryID equals category.ID
                      join catalog in db.BookCatalogs on category.catalogID equals catalog.ID
                      where book.Status == true
                      select new 
                      {
                          ID = book.ID,
                          Name = book.Name,
                          Alias = book.Alias,
                          Price = book.Price,
                          Quanlity = book.Quality,
                          ViewCount = book.ViewCount,
                          Status = book.Status,
                          Image = book.Image,
                          MoreImages = book.MoreImages,
                          PublicationDate = book.PublicationDate,
                          BookCover = book.BookCover,
                          Catalog = catalog.Name,
                          Category = category.Name,
                          Publisher = publisher.Name,
                      });
        return result.ToList();
    }
```

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'  Model

Comment: Use `select new Book` to return `List<Book>` instead of just `select new` which returns anonymous type.

Comment: You could also `.cast()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't convert anonymous type directly to `List<T>`, you have to specify the Class/Type instead.

Set `select new` to `select new Book` for conversion.

```
public List<Book> getListBooks(int top)
{
    var result = (from book in db.Books
                  join author in db.Authors on book.AuthorID equals author.ID
                  join publisher in db.Publishers on book.PublisherID equals publisher.ID
                  join category in db.BookCategories on book.CategoryID equals category.ID
                  join catalog in db.BookCatalogs on category.catalogID equals catalog.ID
                  where book.Status == true
                  select new Book
                  {
                      ID = book.ID,
                      Name = book.Name,
                      Alias = book.Alias,
                      Price = book.Price,
                      Quanlity = book.Quality,
                      ViewCount = book.ViewCount,
                      Status = book.Status,
                      Image = book.Image,
                      MoreImages = book.MoreImages,
                      PublicationDate = book.PublicationDate,
                      BookCover = book.BookCover,
                      Catalog = catalog.Name,
                      Category = category.Name,
                      Publisher = publisher.Name,
                  });
    return result.ToList();
}
```

Also, you can do like this as well.

```
public List<Book> getListBooks(int top)
{
    var result = (from book in db.Books
                  join author in db.Authors on book.AuthorID equals author.ID
                  join publisher in db.Publishers on book.PublisherID equals publisher.ID
                  join category in db.BookCategories on book.CategoryID equals category.ID
                  join catalog in db.BookCatalogs on category.catalogID equals catalog.ID
                  where book.Status == true
                  select new
                  {
                      ID = book.ID,
                      Name = book.Name,
                      Alias = book.Alias,
                      Price = book.Price,
                      Quanlity = book.Quality,
                      ViewCount = book.ViewCount,
                      Status = book.Status,
                      Image = book.Image,
                      MoreImages = book.MoreImages,
                      PublicationDate = book.PublicationDate,
                      BookCover = book.BookCover,
                      Catalog = catalog.Name,
                      Category = category.Name,
                      Publisher = publisher.Name,
                    }).AsEnumerable().Select(x => new Book 
                    {
                      ID,
                      Name,
                      Alias,
                      Price,
                      Quanlity,
                      ViewCount,
                      Status,
                      Image,
                      MoreImages,
                      PublicationDate,
                      BookCover,
                      Catalog,
                      Category,
                      Publisher,
                    }).ToList();
return result.ToList();
}
```